# What does "through" mean here?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

**Through his sleek salesman talk I could discern duplicity.**

Comment: See [through](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/through?q=through#through__17).

Comment: The meaning of through in this context is similar to "by". By his way of speaking (which was like a salesman) you were able to recognize duplicity.

Comment: @Novelcause: In this case, it is rather not 'by', but 'despite of'. Through ("the veil of") his sleek talk (which he used to hide something) I could discern duplicity.

Comment: So does it mean, he saw through his sleek talk and figured out his true intentions?

Comment: @skymninge Well, it depends on how you perceive salesman talk. For me, a sleek salesman talk is a good indication of duplicity itself.. Your point is taken though.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion...

Compare with

> Through the trees I saw a house.
>
> I saw through the trees.
>
> I saw a house through the trees.

The idea here is the speaker can, using a visual metaphor, 'see through' the sleek talk to something the talk doesn't quite 'obscure' - duplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The word **[through](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/through)** has numerous meanings as a preposition, adverb, and adjective. As indicated in several comments to the question, its exact meaning in the above sentence is not obvious.

It could mean *by means of*.

> Based on his sleek salesman talk I could discern duplicity.

It could mean getting *past the limitations of*

> Despite his sleek salesman talk I could discern duplicity.

The latter interpretation is comparable to the use of the phrasal verb *see through*

> Through his sleek salesman talk I could see duplicity

While *discern through* is not a standard phrase, it has a similar sense.

The original sentence makes clear that the speaker has perceived the truth, but it is not clear whether the salesman's talk was an overcome obstacle or a facilitating clue.